# how to integrate tailwind into formik forms

Tags: forms, next.js, tailwind-css, formik

I am trying to implement tailwindcss styles into Formik to style forms. But the styles declared through className are not being applied?
I think Formik is using classname to define input type and tailwind uses the same method to declare styles?
my form page:

```
import React from "react";
import * as yup from "yup"
import { Formik, Form } from 'formik'
import {  MyTextInput } from "../components/FormParts";

let mainFormSchema = yup.object().shape({
    name: yup.string().trim().required()
})

const tryMainForm = () => {
    const initValues = {
        name: ''
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Any place in your app!</h1>
            <Formik
                initialValues={initValues}
                validationSchema={mainFormSchema}
                onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
                        setSubmitting(false);
                    }, 400);
                }}
            >
                {({ isSubmitting }) => (
                    <Form>
                        <MyTextInput
                            label="name"
                            name="name"
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="name"
                        />
                        <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
                            Submit
                        </button>
                    </Form>
                )}
            </Formik>
        </div>
    )
}

export default tryMainForm
```

formpart component:

```
import { useField } from "formik";

export const MyTextInput = ({ label, ...props }) => {
    const [field, meta] = useField(props)
    return (
        <>
            <label htmlFor={props.id || props.name} className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">{label}</label>
            <input className="shadow-sm focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 block w-full sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md" {...field} {...props} />
            {meta.touched && meta.error ? (
                <div className="error">{meta.error}</div>
            ) : null}
        </>
    )
}
```

can you suggest a way to deal with this?
tailwind applies styles properly to label but doesn't with input?

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the field as given below

```
<Form>
<Field name="name" placeholder="name" component={MyTextInput} />
</Form>
```